# Why heap memory usage keeps on going up?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, v8

In the code snippet below I am not adding anything new to DOM, neither do I create any dynamic data type. I also do not increase array size or anything. Yet when you run the code ( must be hosted or local hosted) in Chrome, the value of

```
 performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize
```

keeps on increasing. Why?

```
<html>

<body>
    <p id="memory" style="position: fixed; top:10px; left:10px; font-size: 1.5em;"></p>
    <script>
        setInterval(() => {
            document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML = performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize;
        }, 300);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It is also hosted for you to see (**open in Chrome or Opera** ):

http://appsdepo.com/temp/memory_leak.html

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two allocations in that code:

(1) `performance.memory` creates a new object every time you call it. It's implemented in native code, but the JavaScript equivalent would be roughly:

```
Object.defineProperty(performance.__proto__, "memory", 
                      {get: function() { 
                          return {usedJSHeapSize: ..., 
                                  totalJSHeapSize: ...,
                                  ...: ...};
                      });
```

(2) `usedJSHeapSize` returns a Number, but you're assigning that value to a setter that requires a String, so it is implicitly converted to a String, which is another allocation.

Note that neither of this is a leak: when garbage collection is triggered, all the old temporary objects that are no longer required are cleaned up. It just takes a while until enough garbage is around that Chrome decides that doing some GC is a good use of your CPU.

Comment: I let the code run for an hour. The memory usage kept increasing the whole time. I wonder why CG did not take any action for an hour

Comment: Probably because overall memory consumption was still far away from the limit? How much did it grow in that hour? How often did you check in on it, i.e. would you have noticed if it freed up some memory halfway through and then resumed growing from the resulting lower value? FWIW you can click the trashcan icon in DevTools "Memory" tab to force a full GC cycle and see what it does.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't those objects be allocated on the stack, or is that only done after optimising hot paths and normal young heap space is good enough?

Comment: V8 generally does not allocate objects on the stack, because that doesn't fit JavaScript's semantics well. The only sort-of exception is when the optimizing compiler can prove that a given short-lived object does not "escape", in which case it can (sometimes) avoid the allocation entirely and just keep its individual properties on the stack. So yes, usually the young generation fills that role of efficiently managing short-lived objects.